# How to know correct method of solving problems in probability

Tags: probability

A pack of cards consists of $15$ cards numbered $1$ to $15$. Three cards are drawn at random with replacement. Then, the probability of getting two odd and one even numbered cards, is?

In the above question what is wrong if I solve with following approach:

There are $8$ odd number and $7$ even numbers ,
the number of ways of selection of $2$ odd numbers and $1$ even number is

$8c2$ and $7c1$

$$Probability= \frac{8c2 \times 7c1 \times 3!}{15c3 \times 2!}$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You said you were choosing *with replacement* so, no.  Your method is not the right one.  this is a straight binomial problem with "success" probability (i.e. the probability of getting an odd number) equal to $\frac 8{15}$.

Comment: In reference to lulu's comment, see the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).